# how to read a variable inside service in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I want to know how can I get the value of a variable that is inside a service, I have the following code:

```
myModule.service('notify', ['$window', function(win) {  
       var msgs = []; // I want to read this variable
       this.message = function(msg) {
         msgs.push(msg);
         if (msgs.length == 3) {
           win.alert(msgs.join("\n"));
           msgs = [];
         }
       };
     }]);
```

and I want to read the msgs variable from a controller.

Comment: Just expose a `getMessages()` method that `return msgs;`

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev, The fact that the `message` method is mutating the `msgs` array is indeed undesired and should be avoided. Yet, exposing `msgs` using a method precisely answers the question.

Comment: sorry, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declaring variables with var makes them local to the scope of the function. If you want to expose it you can store it on the object itself.

```
myModule.service('notify', ['$window', function(win) {  
   this.msgs = []; // I want to read this variable
   this.message = function(msg) {
     this.msgs.push(msg);
     if (this.msgs.length == 3) {
       win.alert(this.msgs.join("\n"));
       this.msgs = [];
     }
   };
 }]);
```

Then you can retrieve msgs on your service by reading

```
service.msgs
```

A better pattern would be to create a getter method to retrieve the messages.

```
myModule.service('notify', ['$window', function(win) {  
   var msgs = []; // I want to read this variable
   this.getMessages = function () {
     return msgs;
   };
   this.message = function(msg) {
     msgs.push(msg);
     if (msgs.length == 3) {
       win.alert(msgs.join("\n"));
       msgs = [];
     }
   };
 }]);
```

Then you can retrieve your messages by calling

```
service.getMessages();
```

Answer (score 3):

Services are created with `new` and as a result will expose whatever is attached to `this`.  Simply add a function that returns your messages array to `this`.

```
myModule.service('notify', ['$window', function(win) {  
    var msgs = []; // I want to read this variable

    this.message = function(msg) {
        msgs.push(msg);

        if (msgs.length == 3) {
            win.alert(msgs.join("\n"));
            msgs = [];
        }
    };

    this.getMessages = function () {
        return msgs;
    }
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can use getter for reading

```
myModule.service('notify', ['$window', function (win) {
    var msgs = [];// I prefer _msgs for private variables
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        msgs: {
            get: function () {
                return msgs;
            },
            /*set: function (val) {
                msgs = val;
            },*/ //if you need setter uncomment
            enumerable: true
        }
    });
    //other codes....
}]);
```

Then, you can use `console.log(notify.msgs);` in controller